# How to make the text float around figures in landscape mode?

Tags: floats, landscape

I have a problem with figures in landscape mode. It seems as if they clear the page, then put the figure on the next page, and then the subsequent text is on a third page. Please let me know if the question is unclear, or if additional information is needed. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\begin{document}

The following figure should be inserted on an available page (Figure \ref{fig:test}); 
however, that is not the case. The figure is inserted between this text

\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}  
\centering  
\includegraphics[width=1.4\textwidth, height = 0.75\textwidth] {Figures/example.jpg}
\caption{Example text}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}

and this text. Because of that, I end up with pages that have three sentences, 
and the rest is left blank; the figure is placed on the next page.
Other times, only one-third of the page is left blank. Readers
will think that I begin a new chapter.
What can I do about that? I don't want Latex to break the page whenever I use 
a figure in landscape. Btw: the figures need to be large

\end{document}
```

Comment: landscape uses \clearpage to change the page orientation, perhaps you are looking for `sidewaysfigure` from the `rotating` package which will float a rotated figure in normal pages

Answer (score 2):

The `afterpage` package by David Carlisle may help you here. The body of the `\afterpage` command is processed after the page is filled. MWE:

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,12pt,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}

The following figure should be inserted on an available page (Figure \ref{fig:test}); 
however, that is not the case. The figure is inserted between this text

\afterpage{%
\begin{landscape}%
\begin{figure}%
\centering%
\includegraphics[draft,width=1.4\textwidth, height=0.75\textwidth]{Figures/example.jpg}%
\caption{Example text}%
\label{fig:test}%
\end{figure}%
\end{landscape}%
}

and this text. Because of that, I end up with pages that have three sentences, 
and the rest is left blank; the figure is placed on the next page.
Other times, only one-third of the page is left blank. Readers
will think that I begin a new chapter.
What can I do about that? I don't want Latex to break the page whenever I use 
a figure in landscape. Btw: the figures need to be large

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]